Markdown editor distributed using Flatpak/Appimage/Snap
I'm looking for a Markdown editor to use on my Ubuntu computer that fulfils the following two criteria:

Not WYSIWYG, i.e. with a separate preview pane
Distributed via Flatpak/Appimage/Snap

So far, I know about Ghostwriter from KDE. Are there any others?

VSCode has good in-built Markdown support with separate preview panel. And extensions for extra features if you desire any. It's available on Linux through e.g. Snap.
See documentation.

QOwnNotes has incredible distribution versatility.
https://www.qownnotes.org/installation/.
